# How to read a FASTA file and insert the sequence in another function calling a class?

Tags: python, class, fasta

I have an assignment where I have to write a python class to represent and manipulate biological sequences. I have almost finished the class, however I need to import sequences from FASTA files input the class, so that it can run them. 
In order to run the class in the command line, I was required to create a run_me.py file, which when executed in the command line, should ask for the FASTA file and then run the class.

This is the class constructor:

```
class Bioseq:
    """Biological sequence class"""
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.seq = seq
```

And this is how far I've gotten with the run_me.py file:

```
def read_fasta():
        with open(file_name, "r") as fh:
            line = fh.readline()
            header = ""
            seq = ""
            while line:
                line = line.rstrip('\n')
                if ">" in line:
                    header = line
                else:
                    seq = seq + line
                line = fh.readline()
        return seq
        print(seq)


from TPC2_MR2 import Bioseq
file_name = input("Please enter sequence file name:")
Bioseq = Bioseq(read_fasta())
Bioseq.main()
```

TPC2_MR2 is the name of the class module. 
Now the problem is that when I execute the run_me.py file, I am asked to provide the name of the FASTA file but after that, the sequence is not imported into the class. What should I do?

Please note that I cannot use external Pyhton modules, such as Biopython.

Comment: What do you mean it is not imported into the class? if you do print(Bioseq.seq) you get the sequence. Do note that if you have a fasta file with multiple sequences they all get appended into one sequence.

Comment: There is no connection between the read_fasta function and Bioseq

Comment: What do you mean with connection? With `Bioseq = Bioseq(read_fasta())` you read the data into `self.seq = seq`